# Understanding the API

Tags: c#, api, kentico

So I understand the basic principle of an API, to provide me with access to the core data and functions of the system - in this case Kentico. For example I wanted to get all of the data from the "CMS_Membership" database table, so I started at https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/N_CMS_Membership.htm and there are hundreds of different classes and functions - I tried a few that looked like they might return what I want but no joy.

Do you really use and API by looking for a method name that sounds like what you want? I have heard about "providers" in kentico, are these an easier way to preform common functions? In the end I just wrote a SQL query to go direct to the table which I know is probably wrong.

Comment: Any respectable API should come with at least a modicum of documentation to assist the developers in using it. If not, do complain to the parent company (the existence of the API implies their intent for your consumption).

Comment: I just checked your link and you are browsing the auto-generated documentation, which is more useful for low-level info (class structures, heirarchy, method parameters, etc.)  You probably need to be reading this page instead: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Kentico+9+Documentation+Home;jsessionid=774935347EEC3E2CC472C5E5A3512CA1

Comment: If you could provide a details about what you are trying to do, I would be happy to provide you with a better example of working with the API. You really should avoid going directly to the database, even more so if you plan to edit data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kentico does provide documentation for the API (which is to be used as a reference to specific classes, members etc), such as the page you referenced;
https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/N_CMS_Membership.htm

Kentico also provides separate development documentation on using the API such as;
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Retrieving+database+data+using+ObjectQuery+API

Summarizing what you can read in the link above. For every CMS object you will find;

- A **Table** in the database. Eg. CMS_Membership
- An **Info** class in the API that represents the Table. Eg. MembershipInfo
- An **InfoProvider** class in the API that provides functions to work with the Info class. Eg. MembershipInfoProvider

You can use the ObjectQuery method on the InfoProvider class to return a list of the Info class. Eg. **MembershipInfoProvider.GetMemberships()**

I'm not sure what specifically you want to do with the CMS_Membership table so I will provide an example of getting MembershipInfo data and iterating over it;

```
var members = MembershipInfoProvider.GetMemberships();
foreach (MembershipInfo mi in members)
{
   //iterate over your results
}
```

That is a very simple ObjectQuery, you can expand on this to build complex queries that specify Columns, Where, Order, Top, Join etc.

You may also find these articles on DataQuery helpful;

- http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-dataquery-api
- http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-dataquery-advanced-api

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was going in wrong direction :)